# Assign Java argument values to variables

Tags: java

In a Java program I need to assign command line argument values to variables within the program.

For example the command line has the following
arguments
name=Stan age=50

The program has 2 variables name and age.

I need to assign the value of the arguments to the respective variables
There can be a variable number of arguments passed.

Is there a simple way to do the assignment

Thanks

Comment: You could use a map, instead.

Comment: Show what have you done so far

Comment: Thing is: you learn programming by trying yourself. Not by stopping after reading the assignment and dropping that onto other people.

Answer (score 1):

As Federico has mentioned, it will be easier with a `Map` but I'm not sure if you have reached up to the level where you can use `Map`. Therefore, I've used array in the example given below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "";
        int age = 0;
        // Loop through all the arguments
        for (String s : args) {
            // Split each argument on '='
            String[] parts = s.split("=");
            // The name of the variable is the first part while the second part is value
            if (parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                name = parts[1];
            } else if (parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("age")) {
                try {
                    age = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {// Handle exception in case of non-integer
                    System.out.println("Age must be an integer");
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }

        // Process (e.g. display) name and age
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Name: Stan
Age: 50
```

Comment: "Do my homework questions" without any effort by the OP aren't appreciated here. Same for answers that do all the work. People learn programming by programming, not by copying your input. It is perfectly fair to *explain* the necessary steps, but to give newbies the complete working solution is most likely NOT beneficial for them.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. - Thanks. I will keep this in mind.